# Keeping the same order for a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I need to write a function called `updateHand(hand, word)` which does this:

> Assumes that 'hand' has all the letters in word. In other words, this
> assumes that however many times a letter appears in 'word', 'hand' has
> at least as many of that letter in it.
>
> Updates the hand: uses up the letters in the given word and returns
> the new hand, without those letters in it.
>
> Has no side effects: does not modify hand.
>
> word: string hand: dictionary (string -> int)     returns: dictionary
> (string -> int)

I wrote the code and everything is working except the fact that when 'hand' is returned, it is not in the same order:

```
updateHand({'u': 1, 'q': 1, 'a': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 2, 'i': 1}, 'quail')
```

> {'u': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 1, 'a': 0, 'l': 1, 'q': 0}

Could someone give me the solution or even just a hint to this problem because I don't understand...

Comment: Hi, have you tried using a `collections.OrderedDict`, which preserves order of insertion?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/10987432

Comment: No i haven’t im new to python sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

A dict will not returns the items by insertion order.

What you need is [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = OrderedDict()
my_dict['a'] = 1
...
```

This concerns only python version < 3.6. From python 3.6, the insertion order is kept.